# Where is PIL installed? TideSDK python

Tags: python, tidesdk

I am using Tidesdk and windows7.

PIL was installed in python shown below.

C:\ProgramData\TideSDK\modules\win32\python 
It works in the examination using TideSDK Developer.

If it packs, it stops however, working.

PIL is not installed if packed python is looked at.

If PIL is installed where, does it come to work?